# Why the following ConstraintLayout will push ImageView out of sight when Text of TextView grow?

Tags: android

I have the following `ConstraintLayout` using

- `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"`
- `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"`

This is because I want to components (`TextView` and `ImageView`)

- Close to each others
- Aligned left

They looks like the following

### When Text is short

[image]

However, when the Text is long, the `TextView` tend to push `ImageView` out-of-sight

### When Text is long

[image]

---

May I know why it is so, and how I can fix my `ConstraintLayout`?

As, I'm using `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` for the `ImageView`. Hence, I don't expect it to be pushed out of parent.

The complete XML is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#0fff0000"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:id="@+id/label_text_view"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"

        android:text="Long long long long text"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:id="@+id/sticky_image_view"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:tint="#000000"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sn_baby" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

p/s Please don't suggest me anything other than `ConstraintLayout`. Thank you.

Comment: Use `constrainedWidth=true` property on `TextView`.

Comment: Interesting. It works! Is it because in order to make `wrap_content` of `TextView` work properly, I should use `constrainedWidth=true`? But, how does that related to the position of `ImageView` when the text grown?

Comment: Basically, using textview inside contraint layout meaning that if it's `wrap_content` then parent (as constraint here) allows it to grow no matter what. So, while we set `constrainedHeight/Width` meaning it now respects it's constraints attached to other siblings.